# Make $(document).ready implicit?

Tags: jquery

I check for key-presses like this:

```
   $( document ).ready(function(){
        $( document ).keypress(function() {

           Stuff on keypress


        });
    })
```

Is there some way to not make two nested functions but rather check for the events at once. I know that

```
$( document ).on('ready', 'keypress')
```

will look for ready `OR` keypress. So something similair but rather `AND THEN`, or a way to make ready implicit.

Comment: Put the `.keypress(...)` right before the closing `<body>` tag

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the same event handler to both `ready` (custom jQuery event) and `keyup` (native `onkeyup`) events using this notation:

```
$(document).on('ready keypress', function () {
    // Stuff on keypress
});
```

Comment: `ready` is redundant in the sense than it doesn't need to be used when binding event to document level. BTW, `.on('ready', handler);` syntax shouldn't be used, not using readyPromise internally

Comment: Yes, this is good point :) However it is possible that OP wants the same code for DOMContentLoaded as well as for keyup. So then he actually wants ready event too. In this case it's not redundant.

Comment: Well forgive my comment, looks like OP wants to fire handler on both ready and keypress so... My bad! EDIT: oh ya, just see your edited comment ;)

Comment: No I don't want to run the code on both ready and keypress. If you look at my current solution, it will only run on keypress.

Comment: Then you don't need ready event at all, check A.Wolf answer (if you can).